# Zip and Encryption pods build error in Ensembles 2.6.2

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, ensembles

I created a brand new Xcode project in Swift and integrated Ensembles 2.6.2 via Cocoapods. 
I also wanted to include Zip compression and Encryption and so I simply added these 2 pods in my Podfile, as suggested in the manual.

Unfortunately after running `pod install`, I’m getting an error when trying to build. I attach 2 screenshots to give you some context. Unless I’m missing something really obvious, I have no idea on what to try next.

I'm using Xcode 9.4.1 and macOS 10.13.6

[image]
[image]

Comment: share pod names as you wrote in podFile

Comment: My podfile only contains

   `pod 'Ensembles', '~> 2.0'`
    `pod 'Ensembles/Zip', '~> 2.0'`